# Impact of covid19 in forecasting models

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, forecast

I have sales training data from `2019-06` to `2020-06` and I have to predict sales from `2020-06` to today. The pandemic had a great impact on sales. Are there methods to make my ML forecasting models more robust? Here are some ideas:

- Add a binary variable, `pandemic`, being 1 when `date > 2020-03` and 0 otherwise.
- Alternatively, define two variables `hard_pandemic` and `soft_pandemic` describing respectively the data between March/April 2020 and data after May 2020.
- Weigh the pandemic data more, since they describe better the current situation.

Are there drawbacks to these methods? Are there alternative ways to improve this?